# ASP method inside javascript code not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

We have an asp application under mono 2.6 (debian server), after upgrading to 2.10 we have this situation:

Simple code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--

var x = "<%= 2+2 %>";

//--></script>
```

When testing it in the browser i found this source

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--

x = "<%= 2+2 %>";

//--></script>
```

**The asp tag was not interpreted!**

but if I remove " < !-- " and "//-->" inside the tag < script ...>, all works fine

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var x = "<%= 2+2 %>";

</script>
```

it work!!!

Comment: try  <!-<%=""%>- , may it will bypass this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The tags `<!--` and `-->` are used to comment out multiple lines in html while `//` comments out single javascript line, they prevent your code to execute, just remove them.

Comment: yes sure, but what I do not understand is why the ASP (server) code is not interpreted if inside a scrpt tag + html comment